# How to enable animation for Geolocate Control?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Using Mapbox GL JS ver. 1.10.1

I've already got the map working with everything, but when I click the Geolocate Control button there's no animation. It just jumps to a point so I'd like to know how to add that animation. The [mapbox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/locate-user/) shows the behavior I want but I can't find what I might've missed to make the animation work.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
var geoctrl = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
     positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
     },
     trackUserLocation: true
  }); 

this.map.addControl(geoctrl);
```

I've tried using the exact code in the documentation, removing parameters and  setting the parameters to false and there's still no animation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're saying the demo animates fine for you? But your code which is very similar to the demo doesn't animate? Can you just keep refining your code to be closer and closer to the demo?

Comment: I was referring to the mapbox documentation examples for using the geo location control that's on the website, not using a demo. Like I mentioned in my question, I tried using the exact same code from the documentation and there's still no animation so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by demo. You haven't really provided enough information here for anyone else to help you understand why that demo works, but your code (which you claim has essentially the same code) doesn't.

Comment: Sorry about that Steve. I'm still new with mapbox so I can't explain the issue better than I did. However, I figured out what the problem was after talking to the mapbox devs. Turns out that I had a the "show animations in Windows" setting turned off so that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed this issue. Turns out it was a windows setting for enabling animations on windows. I'm using rdp so turning off animations helped to improve the connection.

See [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion) for more info